# Switch between add/remove button with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

### The goal

Switch between add/remove button based on availability using KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I need to add a product/item to my summary. If the product is already on summary, then changes the "add button" into "remove button" or else changes from "remove button" to "add button"

Until here, just concept, right? Yea, but I think I'm missing the logic of the trouble.

Look:

```
<!-- ko foreach: products -->
    <!-- ko if: isAdded -->
        <button class="btn btn-small btn-success action remove">
            <i class="icon-ok"></i>
        </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: isAdded -->
      <form action="#" data-bind="submit: add">
        <button class="btn btn-small action add">
            <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

As you can see, there is conditions to check if a *specific* product is added or not. If the list is empty, nothing appears; If I add something manually by code, the two buttons appears — remove and add button.

[I made this CodePen](http://codepen.io/chiefGui/pen/dHlwE) to simulate the scenario.

Can someone help me?

### Some details

I *can* use jQuery; I'm already working on it for about three weeks and until now, no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you don't take full advantage of knockoutjs (but that could just be because I don't see the full application). I however rewrote it a bit and put up an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riri78/G8zPT/) (jsfiddle).

```
function Product(name, desc) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.desc = ko.observable(desc);
    self.isAdded = ko.observable(false);
};

function SummaryViewModel(products) {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray(products);

    self.add = function (item) {
        var i = self.products.indexOf(item);
        self.products()[i].isAdded(true);
    };

    self.remove = function (item) {
        var i = self.products.indexOf(item);
        self.products()[i].isAdded(false);
    };
};

var p = [new Product("One", "Yep one"), new Product("Two", "nope, two")];
ko.applyBindings(new SummaryViewModel(p));
```

Comment: Hello, Riri. I'm not taking full advantage of KnockoutJS because I don't know how to do this. And I'm using `submit` data-binding instead of `click` and I do not have `item`. Any suggest? (By the way, thanks!)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Didn't intend to point out that you "don't take full advantage" - just justifying me changing a few things ;).
 
The "item" is the first model parameter passed in a click, check the docs [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Using `click` instead of submit is up to you. But if you need to post anything it should probably be as just a ajax post within the `add`/`remove` or as it's own `save` method maybe? I didn't understand the use of id so I skipped them.
Hope that helps. Thank me by voting. ;)